# Differentiate between iVar and Method Parameter?

Tags: objective-c

I have a property like this:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIImageView *backgroundImageHolder;
```

I want to adjust the setter, and XCode fills out the method signature like this:

```
-(void)setBackgroundImageHolder:(UIImageView *)backgroundImageHolder {
```

However, to actually do anything in the method, I must change the parameter `backgroundImageHolder` to something like `backgroundImageHolderIn`. Is there any way to avoid this? Is there any way to set the iVar without reinvoking the setter (causing an endless loop), or just referring to the parameter again?

I just tried:

```
self->backgroundImageHolder = backgroundImageHolder;
```

but the compiler warns me anyway.

**Note:** I am using the automagically generated iVar that the compiler makes for the property, but by default its name is the same.

Comment: I've wondered this myself, I often want to check what the previous value of an ivar was in a custom accessor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can give tell the compiler how to name the generated ivar:

```
@synthesize propertyName = iVarName;
```

If there actually exists an ivar named `iVarName` that one is used. If it doesn't exist the compiler creates it for you.

Like:

```
@synthesize backgroundImageHolder = myBackgroundImageHolder;
```

Now you can access the instance variable `myBackgroundImageHolder`. You don't need to declare it in the interface first.

Comment: +1 I should've mentioned in the question that I already knew about this possibility. At the very least you didn't explicitly declare the iVar, which is irrelevant.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the conflicting parameter name seems to be pretty well covered by now. Basically, you have to either:

- Rename the incoming argument
- Rename the synthesized iVar

Once you have a method argument that differs from the iVar you're attempting to set, you have everything you need to write a custom setter. To avoid the infinite loop, you have to not call the setter you're currently implementing, whether it be via dot syntax or method brace syntax. Instead, refer directly to the backing iVar. You'll need to take care to manually implement the memory management semantics you declared in the property though (assign vs. retain, etc.):

```
// Backed by _myProperty iVar.
- (void)setMyProperty:(NSInteger)myProperty {

    // Insert custom code here...

    [self setMyProperty:myProperty]; // Obviously bad.

    self.myProperty = myProperty;    // Less obviously bad (thanks dot syntax)
                                     // but semantically identical to the previous line.

    _myProperty = myProperty         // Good, (assuming assign semantics).
}
```

Comment: If I can't have a better solution, at least I can have a comprehensive answer. Nice, thanks! Also, should say, "assuming assign semantics or ARC" which my example makes clear with `strong`

Comment: @Yar: Yeah, I missed the `strong`. In that case, you don't have to worry, as iVars are synthesized with the appropriate ownership qualifiers.

Answer (score 0):

Compiler warns you because when you declare `@property` it creates instance variable with exact same name as a property (and as a parameter of a setter method). One way to avoid it is to create differently named instance variable and then pair it with property using `@synthesize` like this:

```
// .h
@interface Foo : NSObject {
    IBOutlet UIImageView *myfooImageView;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) UIImageView *publicFooImageView;

// .m
@implementation Foo
@synthesize publicFooImageView=myfooImageView;
@end
```

Answer (score 0):

The clearest thing to do would be this:

In your header, define an iVar for backgroundImageHolder like so

```
@interface Something : NSObject
{
  IBOutlet UIImageView *_backgroundImageHolder
}
```

Notice the leading underscore.

Then in your .m file, use either the synthesize call like so:

```
@synthesize backgroundImageHolder=_backgroundImageHolder;
```

or just define the getter and setter methods yourself: Then you are able to access the ivar via "_backgroundImageHolder" without any danger of accidentally calling the setter again.

Comment: Note that you don't need to declare the iVar in the interface in the header. I usually don't since it's really an implementation detail that doesn't concern consumers of the class.

Comment: Hmmm... thanks. I already knew about this option, and the problem is that it's a ton of code for little gain. Having to declare redundant iVars for properties is simply horrid.

Comment: Correct. I sometimes like to explicitly declare them for readability, but it's not necessary.